# Viewport for non responsive page?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has a width of 600px and non responsive. However, I couldnt make the width full stretched to device's width.

```
<style>
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0px
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600">
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: have you tried `width=device-width` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `width=device-width` this way:

```
<style>
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;     /* Center the body */
  max-width: 600px;   /* Your app width. */
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```